# How to add decimal numbers in array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Hi i am working on javascript and here i am working on sum of float numbers but i am getting wrong result

```js
var studentsList = [
  { name: 'A', rollNo: 1, mark: "6.75" },
  { name: 'B', rollNo: 2, mark: "3.5" },
  { name: 'C', rollNo: 3, mark: "4.25" },
  { name: 'A', rollNo: 1, mark: "3.5" }
];

var byName1 = {};
for (var student of studentsList) {
  if (student.name in byName1) {
    byName1[student.name].mark += parseFloat(student.mark);
  } else {
    byName1[student.name] = { ...student };
  }
}
console.log(Object.values(byName1));
```

But the actual result is 10.25.

How to do it? TIA.

Comment: The problem is that in your `studentsList`, you actually have strings instead of numbers. You need to convert those into numbers first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `parseFloat` the `byName1[student.name].mark` too, to do addition with `parseFloat(student.mark)` because `byName1[student.name].mark` is a string.

```js
var studentsList = [
  { name: 'A', rollNo: 1, mark: "6.75" },
  { name: 'B', rollNo: 2, mark: "3.5" },
  { name: 'C', rollNo: 3, mark: "4.25" },
  { name: 'A', rollNo: 1, mark: "3.5" }
];

var byName1 = {};
for (var student of studentsList) {
  if (student.name in byName1) {
    byName1[student.name].mark = parseFloat(byName1[student.name].mark) + parseFloat(student.mark);
  } else {
    byName1[student.name] = { ...student };
  }
}
console.log(Object.values(byName1));
```

But if you use float instead of string for the mark it'd be cleaner.